# Dynamic data set in function without use multiple if else

Tags: javascript

I have below code for test and set the boolean variables firstEmpty,secondEmpty,thirdEmpty. But in another validation, i have 7 variables to set . it will take more than 50 if else.

Need help to optimize dynamic code.

```
    dataValidation=(first,second,third)=>{
       let arr = this.state.datafirst;
       var checkfirst = arr.findIndex((item) => item.value === first);
       
       let arr1 = this.state.datasecond;
       var checksecond = arr1.findIndex((item) => item.value === second);
       
        let arr2 = this.state.datathird;
        var checkthird = arr2.findIndex((item) => item.value === third);
      
        if(checkfirst === -1 && checksecond === -1 && checkthird === -1){
            this.firstEmpty = true;
            this.secondEmpty = true;
            this.thirdEmpty = true; 
            return 0;
        } else if(checkfirst === -1 && checksecond === -1) { 
            this.firstEmpty = true;
            this.secondEmpty = true;    
            return 0;          
        } else if(checksecond === -1 && checkthird === -1) { 
            this.secondEmpty = true;
            this.thirdEmpty = true;
            return 0;
        }  else if(checkfirst === -1 && checkthird === -1) { 
            this.firstEmpty = true;
            this.thirdEmpty = true; 
            return 0;          
        }  else if(checkfirst === -1) { 
            this.firstEmpty = true; 
            return 0;
        }  else if(checksecond === -1) { 
            this.secondEmpty = true;
            return 0;
        }  else if(checkthird === -1) { 
            this.thirdEmpty = true; 
            return 0;
        } else { 
            return 1;
        } 
  }
```

Comment: You can use array in HTMLcontrol and user for loop in javascript for check the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I optimize function lie below. It is working now. thanks for all answer.

```
dataValidation=(first,second,third)=>{
       let arr = this.state.datafirst;
       var checkfirst = arr.findIndex((item) => item.value === first);
       
       let arr1 = this.state.datasecond;
       var checksecond = arr1.findIndex((item) => item.value === second);
       
        let arr2 = this.state.datathird;
        var checkthird = arr2.findIndex((item) => item.value === third);
      
      
      this.dataCheck =1; 
        if(checkfirst === -1 ){  this.firstEmpty  = true;  this.dataCheck =0;} 
        if(checksecond === -1 ){ this.secondEmpty = true; this.dataCheck =0;}  
        if(checkthird === -1 ){ this.thirdEmpty = true; this.dataCheck =0;}  
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as just optimizing your existing code, I'm pretty sure this does exactly the same thing:

```
dataValidation=(first,second,third)=>{
    let arr = this.state.datafirst;
    let arr1 = this.state.datasecond;
    let arr2 = this.state.datasecond;
    this.firstEmpty = !arr.some((item) => item.value === first);
    this.secondEmpty = !arr1.some((item) => item.value === second);
    this.thirdEmpty = !arr2.some((item) => item.value === third);
    return (this.firstEmpty || this.secondEmpty || this.thirdEmpty) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Or even more dynamic, perhaps:

```
dataValidation=(first,second,third)=>{
    const data = { first, second, third }
    const retVal = 1;
    Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
        let arr = this.state[`data${key}`];
        this[`${key}Empty`] = !arr.some((item) => item.value === data[key]);
        if (this[`${key}Empty`]) retVal = 0;
    });
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
this.firstEmpty = checkfirst === -1;
this.secondEmpty = checksecond === -1;
this.thirdEmpty = checkthird === -1;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value